# Find the value of $ k $ such that the following is a probability distribution of a random variable X:

Tags: probability

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{x} & -6 & -3 & 2 & 5 \\ \hline
\text{P(X = x)} & \frac{k+3}{26} & \frac{4k-1}{26} & \frac{2k+5}{26} & \frac{k+1}{26}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

For some reason, I keep thinking all I have to do to find k is sum up the bottom row and let it = 1. But I think I'm wrong, can anyone help me walk through this?

Comment: No, you're right. Check also after that that everything is non-negative.

Comment: That's interesting. So the x values in the top row is irrelevant? I'm actually resitting probability 1 in uni, so I'm practicing some past papers. That question happens to be 5 marks. If that's how I get k, then I really do wonder how I failed the first time around. Anyways, thank you :)

Comment: Yes, in that exercise they are irrelevant. It could have been $\sqcup$, $\square$, $\dagger$, and $\diamond$ instead of $-6,-3,2,5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list of $x$ is exhaustive and there are no other possible values for $x$, the probabilities should add to one, yes.

Comment: **and** be non-negative. It's always a good idea to check that, for instance, $\Pr[X=-3]\geq 0$.